# Recursively find all files under directory A, write "abc" to these files. Only to Files

Tags: shell

I think this is gonna close to work

```
find /mydirectory -name '*'  | xargs echo abc >
```

But I got:

```
find: paths must precede expression: b
```

Need a little help :)
thanks

Comment: I think your issue is the abc > Newline. The pipe forwards the output of find to xargs, but echo doesn't know what file to write the 'abc' to. But shell is definitely not my forte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'echo "abc" >> ${1}' _ "{}" \;
```

Or if you want to do it in bulk:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'for f; do echo "abc" >> $f; done' _ "{}" +
```

If you need explanations, ask.

[This](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) page is a good guide on how to use find.

In both commands, the `_` and `{}` are passed as arguments to the `sh` command.  Because $0 isn't fully reliable to use (see the linked page), a dummy variable `_` is passed to it.

Find puts its matches in `{}`, which is expanded.  So if the command matches a file `a`, then `{}` is expanded to `a` in the first command.

In the first command, the command you are passing to exec is terminated with `;`, but `;` is special to the shell, so you escape it.

The second command runs as a bulk operation, so if find matches `a`, `b`, and `c` (etc.), the `{}` is expanded to all three and passed in.

Thus, you need a `for f` in the second command, which defaults to `for f in $@`, which will be your `a`, `b`, and `c` (and this can be tested by doing ${1}, ${2}, ${3}...).

Comment: Hi @twmb thank you. what do "_ {} \" in your command? thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by writing another script that takes a number of file names as arguments and does the echo on them. Then, instead of using echo, call this script with xargs. You can also add `-type f` to `find` so that it omits directories.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with bash:

```
for f in $(find /mydirectory -type f); do echo 'abc' > "$f"; done
```